# Electrons under effect of induced electric field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Suppose a magnetic field exists in a region $0<r<a$ and a circular wire loop (conductor) is placed around it such that its radius is more than $a$.
If the rate of increase of flux is proportional to time then there will be a time-independent induced electric field inside the wire loop. As the field is non-conservative it does some work on the electrons and hence the speed of electrons should increase. So why doesn't the current in the loop increase as we know that $i=nAev$ where $v$ is the drift speed of electron?

Comment: If there is no resistance in the wire, the constant emf will result in an increasing current.

Comment: > *"So why doesnt the current in the loop increase"* Why do you think it does not increase? If net emf pushes current in its direction, current will increase.

Comment: In many textbook questions they ask net current in such problems so do they ask the current only at the beginning?